# Internationally pretty print string objects that contain decimals

Tags: javascript, string, internationalization, decimal, pretty-print

I am using [MikeMcl's big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) for precise accounting which outputs a string when calling `toFixed()`.

I'd like to pretty print decimal results in an internationally aware way much like how the [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) can automatically print [dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) and [times](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) in a local format.

Is there a way to format string objects that contain decimals internationally?

Answer (score 1):

```
var myNumber = 123456.78;
console.log(myNumber.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: Correct, but it gets you the local decimal symbol and digit grouping symbol.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job.

```
function localize(fixed) {
  /*Determine decimal symbol and digit grouping symbol.*/
  var decimalSymbol = '.';
  var digitGroupingSymbol = ',';
  var dummy = 1234.5;
  testResult = dummy.toLocaleString();
  /*Browsers using digit grouping symbol.*/
  if (testResult.length === 7) {
    decimalSymbol = testResult[5];
    digitGroupingSymbol = testResult[1];
  }
  /*Browsers not using digit grouping symbol.*/
  if (testResult.length === 6) {
    decimalSymbol = testResult[4];
    digitGroupingSymbol = (decimalSymbol === '.'? ',': '.');
  }
  /*Format the number.*/
  var result = '';
  var dsIndex = fixed.indexOf('.');
  if (dsIndex < 0) {
    throw new Error('Expected decimal separator \'.\' in "' + fixed + '".');
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < dsIndex; ++i) {
    if (fixed[i] < '0' || fixed[i] > '9') {
      throw new Error('Expected digit, got "' + fixed[i] + '".');
    }
    if (i > 0 && i%3 === dsIndex%3) result += digitGroupingSymbol ;
    result += fixed[i];
  }
  result += decimalSymbol + fixed.substr(dsIndex + 1);
  return result;
}  

/*Demonstration*/
var n1 = '123.4567890';
console.assert(localize(n1));
var n2 = '1234.567890';
console.log(localize(n2));
var n3 = '123456789012345678.1234567890';
console.log(localize(n3));
var n4 = '1234567890123456789.1234567890';
console.log(localize(n4));
var n5 = '12345678901234567890.1234567890';
console.log(localize(n5));
```

Output:
123.4567890
1.234.567890
123.456.789.012.345.678.1234567890
1.234.567.890.123.456.789.1234567890
12.345.678.901.234.567.890.1234567890

Comment: I didn't check what current browsers can return on `dummy.toLocaleString()` but as an example I implemented a default and 2 specific replies. B.t.w. Firefox 28.0 with my locale replies 1,234.5.

Comment: If the current implementation isn't fast enough. We can split the function in a function detectLocale() returning a locale and another function localize(locale, fixed).